# OSX framework 10.13 fails to compile ImageKit.framework and ImageKit.framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks, clang++

I just updated to the newest OSX and newest Xcode and now I cannot compile my code anymore, because I include AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h and I get this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioQueue.h:867:30: error: 
      expected ','
                                                                                API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.6), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0));
                                                                                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioQueue.h:902:30: error: 
      expected ','
                                                                                API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.6), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0));
```

Similar situation for ImageKit.framework:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Headers/IKImageBrowserView.h:171:73: error: 
      expected ','
API_DEPRECATED("Deprecated - Please use NSCollectionView instead", macos(10.5, 10.14))
```

Seems like the macos macro is messed up or something, but all that is in the system framework... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - apparently an order matters... I was also including OpenGL stuff, and just shuffling the includes solved it. Oh well...